# setting background-image using react styling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, image

i am making a project of my own and i am trying to display 3 components that will render a different image for one of them. The image is not displaying, i think the problem is the server is downloading the image  as a html/text type. I am new to react and i am having difficulties displaying images...

style={{backgroundImage: `url(${props.img})`} }

img={city.imageURL}

imageURL: '/assets/mount-fugji.png'

And by the way, how do i access the style object ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like

```js
 <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.img || city.imageURL})` }} />;
```

Comment: Its still not working, anyways, thank you !

Answer (score 0):

In React you should use:

```
styles={{ backgroundImage:`url(${picture})` }}
```

so you can try to edit code like this:

```
style={{backgroundImage: `url(${props.img})`} }
```